# Having Trouble adding UEFI entry using efibootmgr

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios

I am trying to rename the boot label of ubuntu. In order to rename the label, I have to delete the entry and create it again. However `efibootmgr` seem to not recognize the correct partition. Here is what I do to create the entry:

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -w -l \\EFI\\ubuntu\\shimx64.efi -L "Lubuntu" -p 2 -d /dev/sdb2
```

This works, however right after I reboot this entry is deleted.
When I do `efibootmgr -v` I get this

```
Boot0003* Lubuntu   HD(2,0,0,500a0dff)File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0007* Ubuntu    HD(2,1f4800,82000,adcf2808-6afb-47fc-be64-5ce73ca83859)File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot00A5* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,1f4800,82000,adcf2808-6afb-47fc-be64-5ce73ca83859)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...s................
```

"Ubuntu" is the working entry. As you can clearly see, they are pointing to totally different places, yet the files are in the same place.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-d` option to `efibootmgr` takes a *whole-disk* device, such as `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb`, ***not*** a partition (such as the `/dev/sdb2` you've provided). The `-p` option identifies the partition on the disk, which in your example you've set to `2`.