# efi boot order changes on package upgrade

Tags: 16.04, uefi, efibootmgr

Every now and then after I upgrade my system the efi boot order is changed and the system won't boot. I have to go to the bios and reselect the ubuntu efi entry. I am guessing it is one of those packages (at least it always happens when I see one of those being upgraded):

```
grub-common grub-efi grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-
signed grub2-common shim shim-signed
```

When I run efibootmgr I get this:

```
efibootmgr
No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recovery
```

I ran:

```
[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS
UEFI
```

I am unable to find any answers to efibootgmr not running. Please help. Thanks!

Update:

I tried adding an EFI boot variable with:

```
efibootmgr --create --disk /dev/sda --part 1 --label "Ubuntu" --loader
\\EFI\\ubuntu\\grubx64.efi
```

Which returns:

```
BootOrder: 0000
Boot0000* Ubuntu
```

On restart the system won't boot.

[Boot Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylYrh.jpg)

Now the working entry is labeled Ubuntu. When I select it Ubuntu boots. After running efibootmgr again I get the same result as before:

```
efibootmgr
No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recover
```

In case it is relevant shim and shim-signed were also updated when the boot order was changed by the update.

Update:

The computer is a Gigabyte Brix GB-BXBT-1900 with the newest bios revision.

I think my initial question was why efigootmgr is not working and that has been answered. Thank you for your input.

Comment: What brand/model system. Some violate UEFI standard and only boot entry labeled "Windows Boot Manager". If not dual booting you can make Windows entry actually use grub or shim file to boot. You can make the fallback or hard drive entry use grub or shim. Or use eEFInd boot manage. Details: Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789
Boot-Repair should automatically do this with 'use standard EFI file':
http://askubuntu.com/questions/582073/dual-boot-but-only-windows-boots/582114#582114

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into what I call a "boot coup." I've written a page on this subject; see [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html) for details. That said, your problem sounds a bit unusual, but it is likely related to this:

```
efibootmgr
No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recovery
```

Ordinarily, an EFI-based computer does have a `BootOrder` variable set. The cases *I* personally have seen where it's not set have been because of a defective firmware that simply refuses to accept this variable. On such computers, the only chance of booting is via a fallback filename (typically `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` on the ESP, although `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` will sometimes work, too). That said, I have heard of cases where the `BootOrder` variable is empty but can be set. In this case, adding an EFI boot variable, as described [here,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383166/having-trouble-adding-uefi-entry-using-efibootmgr) can fix the problem.

If your computer is just badly defective and needs to boot through a fallback filename, you must copy or move/rename the boot loader to the appropriate name, and possibly support files like configuration files.

Given that you referred to "the ubuntu efi entry" makes me think that you've got boot variables, but the `BootOrder` variable is getting lost. This is probably a firmware bug, although it could indicate defective NVRAM hardware. Upgrading the firmware might fix the problem, if it's a bug. Check with the manufacturer to see if such an upgrade exists. If that doesn't help, you might copy GRUB to the fallback filename, where it should be called if/when the `BootOrder` variable is lost again. The ESP is normally mounted at `/boot/efi`, and normal Linux filesystem commands work on it, so you can do this:

```
sudo cp -r /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT
sudo mv /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/shimx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi
```

This copies Shim to the fallback filename. If you're certain that your computer doesn't use Secure Boot, you could rename `grubx64.efi`, rather than `shimx64.efi`, to `bootx64.efi`.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 or later uses umask=0077 to mount ESP in fstab. The older versions used "defaults". Boot-Repair, if run, auto adds a new entry with defaults, so it can edit the ESP. Not sure if the umask=0077 is for security reasons or not, but it prevents anyone from editing ESP which often is required. For more details: http://askubuntu.com/questions/794725/can-i-remove-windows-boot-manager-from-dedicated-ubuntu-computer?noredirect=1#comment1197619_794725