# Can't boot Ubuntu after installing and use Boot-Repair

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I bought a Windows 10 notebook and need Linux on it (my first linux experience).
The notebook only have a 32gb ssd, I use a linux live with Ubuntu 16.04 and did not boot after successfull installation (I choose to format everything). I use `boot-repair` and still not booting (http://paste2.org/hJ9XGkJy), already put the ssd on priority of booting. I tried to install grub with mount but show errors like `failed to get canonical path of 'aufs'`. Please some help, I already read a ton of other pages and lost a day with this (trying the same method over and over).

Comment: Can you give us more details, of what you did? And what got accomplished? Are you even able to boot in Live Mode?

Comment: yes, when I plug the live I can use the options (use without installation, install, etc...)

Comment: Does the try without installation option works?

Comment: Yes, I use boot-repair from the use without installation.

Comment: Boot-Repair says you have Secure boot on. Have you tried with it off? You show an Ubuntu entry in UEFI, but it is not in default boot order. Can you manually boot from UEFI boot menu?

Comment: @oldfred Idk if I understand the question, I can't boot without the usb and I can only install ubuntu or use without installing, I can't boot in the installed version. The boot order is in default order, I set after installing the ubuntu. How can I tried with secure boot off?

Answer (score 1):

Your computer uses an NVMe disk, which appears in Ubuntu via the `/dev/mmcblk0` device. Most disks in Ubuntu appear via devices called `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, and so on. It looks like Boot Repair might not be quite handling that correctly. At the very least, it's not showing the partition table on your `/dev/mmcblk0` device. Although the repair looks like it probably did what it should have done, there are also some errors reported (like on line 676 and 679), so I'm not 100% sure that it's completed correctly. I recommend you contact the Boot Repair developers about this; NVMe disks with filenames of the form `/dev/mmcblk*` are becoming more common, and Boot Repair should be able to handle them correctly.

That said, if these issues aren't critical (and they may not be), it's possible that your firmware is one of the still-too-common broken EFIs that forget or ignore their built-in boot managers' NVRAM-based boot entries. I say this because the first `efibootmgr` output, on lines 254-264, shows a `BootOrder` variable that does not include the `ubuntu` entry. The same is true of the second `efibootmgr` output, on lines 624-634. The third instance, on lines 656-666, shows the result of the repair and shows the `ubuntu` entry as being active and the default option in the `BootOrder`. The thing is that the `BootOrder` variable should have been correct from the start; the fact that it wasn't correct, but that an `ubuntu` entry was present, implies that the `BootOrder` variable was altered after the OS was installed. The usual cause of this problem is a defective firmware.

If I'm right, you may need to either return the computer for a refund (if it's new enough for this) or use an ugly, hackish workaround, as described in my answer to [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902800/efi-boot-order-changes-on-package-upgrade) The Boot Repair utility can also do this semi-automatically; you need to set the option to back up and rename boot loaders on the "advanced" menu, then re-repair the installation.

Comment: I use boot repair with the option to back up and rename boot loaders on the advanced menu and http://paste2.org/k0OaBD99 still not booting

Comment: Can you try booting with my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on a USB flash drive? (There's a download link on that page.) If you can boot via rEFInd, you could try installing it via its Debian package or PPA; but given the fact that your boot order is being forgotten, you may need to do a `sudo mvrefind /boot/efi/EFI/refind /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT` after installing it.

Comment: I tried the rEFInd
Installing rEFInd to the ESP...
mount: special device /dev/mmcblk01 does not exist
unmount: //boot/efi: not mounted
dpkg: error processing package refind (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

Comment: Oh man, i got it, thank you so much, I set the boot manually in the bios after redo the reboot like you said and copy the archives, THANK YOOOUUUUU